# Return name of object from table with max value lua

Tags: object, lua, max

I was trying to return name of object with max value. Let's suppose this information:

```
maxTreeHeight = 0
maxTreeName = ""
maxLeaveLength = 0
maxLeaveName = "" 

fruitTab =
 {
   oF = { name = "Orange", avgTreeHeight = 32, avgLeaveLength = 0.27 },
   aF = { name = "Apple", avgTreeHeight = 10, avgLeaveLength = 0.14 },
   bF = { name = "Banana", avgTreeHeight = 16, avgLeaveLength = 8.9 },
   mF = { name = "Mango", avgTreeHeight = 115, avgLeaveLength = 0.98 }  
 }

--below in function
 for i, v in ipairs(fruitTab) do
   if v.avgTreeHeight > maxTreeHeight then
      maxTreeHeight = v.avgTreeHeight
      maxTreeName  = v.name
   end
   if v.avgLeaveLength > maxLeaveLength then
      maxLeaveLength = v.avgLeaveLength
      maxLeaveName = v.name
   end
 end

   print(maxLeaveName.." "..maxLeaveLength )
   print(maxTreeName.." "..maxTreeHeight)
```

This type of setup is what I've tried to extract the information that I want, but the function isn't always giving me accurate values(the names said to have max value are not always correct from what I can tell)

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Can you give an actual example of a situation that doesnt work? Note that the variables are global, so you can not run this function multiple times on different tables and expect the results to be what you likely expected.

Comment: unknown event was causing values to go crazy. Thank you for feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you're getting any results with that code, unless some of your input tables are keyless.

The [`ipairs`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-ipairs) function iterates through the *indices* of a table, intended for use with *array-like* tables. Instead, you should use the [`pairs`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-pairs) function, which iterates through each *field* in a table, by using [`next`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-next).

Simply making that change yields results from your example code.

Here is some further updated code:

```
function get_max (tab)
    local maxTreeHeight = 0
    local maxTreeName = ""
    local maxLeaveLength = 0
    local maxLeaveName = ""

    for _, v in pairs(tab) do
       if v.avgTreeHeight > maxTreeHeight then
          maxTreeHeight = v.avgTreeHeight
          maxTreeName  = v.name
       end

       if v.avgLeaveLength > maxLeaveLength then
          maxLeaveLength = v.avgLeaveLength
          maxLeaveName = v.name
       end
    end

    print(maxLeaveName.." "..maxLeaveLength )
    print(maxTreeName.." "..maxTreeHeight)
end

local fruitTab = {
    oF = { name = "Orange", avgTreeHeight = 32, avgLeaveLength = 0.27 },
    aF = { name = "Apple", avgTreeHeight = 10, avgLeaveLength = 0.14 },
    bF = { name = "Banana", avgTreeHeight = 16, avgLeaveLength = 8.9 },
    mF = { name = "Mango", avgTreeHeight = 115, avgLeaveLength = 0.98 }  
}

get_max(fruitTab)
```